# Date Difference within a group in R and creating a new column based on certain conditions

Tags: r

Need assistance in creating a new data frame which will have columns called Name and Value_2. 
Existing data frame includes columns like Name, Date and Value_1. The new data frame will be created using an existing data frame which follows a condition. Below is the existing data frame for better clarity:-

```
Name    Date       Value_1
A       9/28/2011  12345
A       1/8/2012   23456
A       6/3/2013   78910
B       10/4/2010  438504
B       10/14/2013 439587
C       8/22/2013  436096
D       4/20/2010  3258043
D       3/24/2013  968347
D       7/8/2013   954733
D       8/19/2013  438578
```

In group name A, the first test was conducted on 9/28/2011 with a value_1 of 12345 and the last test was conducted on 6/3/2013 with a value_1 of 23456. Hence the value_2 in a new data frame follows a condition to check if log10(12345 ) -log10(23456) >=2 and categorize group name A into Yes/No in value_2 column of ne data frame. A similar condition needs to be followed with other groups as well. Below is the desired output for your reference :-

```
Name    Value_2
A       No
B       Yes
C       Yes
D       No
```

Value_2 here follows the condition of log10(first test date value_1)-log10(last test date value_1)>=2.

Comment: Why is C Yes? What is the special condition when the first test is also the last test? Actually I get different results for everything.

Comment: The value in `6/3/2013` is `78910`, not `23456`

Comment: Looking at `tapply(dat$Value_1,dat$Name,log10)` I can't see how you are getting any differences `>=2`.

Comment: @thelatemail The desired data frame I have generated is a random example but not the output of following the log condition. With respect to C, where there is only one row or one test conducted we can follow the rule of log(436096)-log(436096) which will be equal to 0 and hence the value_2 will have a output of "No"

Comment: @thelatemail We can neglect the rows, where there is only one test conducted. In the final stages we can directly impute those values to "No".

Answer (score 1):

This is a `split-apply-combine` problem, which suggests functions like `tapply` `by` `ave` and `aggregate` and the extension packages `plyr`, `dplyr` or even `data.table`. In this case, a simple `tapply` or `aggregate` can work depending on what output format you want (using @Robert's `Data`):

```
Data <- Data[order(Data$Name, as.Date(Data$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")),]

tapply(log10(Data$Value_1), Data$Name, function(x) head(x,1) - tail(x,1) >= 2)
#    A     B     C     D 
#FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE 

aggregate(log10(Data["Value_1"]), Data["Name"], FUN=function(x) head(x,1) - tail(x,1) >= 2)
#  Name Value_1
#1    A   FALSE
#2    B   FALSE
#3    C   FALSE
#4    D    TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Data <- read.table(textConnection("
Name    Date       Value_1
A       9/28/2011  12345
A       1/8/2012   23456
A       6/3/2013   78910
B       10/4/2010  438504
B       10/14/2013 439587
C       8/22/2013  436096
D       4/20/2010  3253043
D       3/24/2013  968347
D       7/8/2013   954733
D       8/19/2013  438"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE,head=TRUE)

Data$Date=as.Date(Data$Date,"%m/%d/%Y")
Names=unique(Data$Name)
sdf=lapply(Names,function(x)Data[Data$Name == x,])
Value_2=sapply(sdf,function(dt){
  rx=dt$Date%in%range(dt$Date)
  if (length(rx)==1) return("No") else
  return(ifelse(-diff(log10(dt$Value_1[rx]))>=2,"Yes","No"))
})
data.frame(Names,Value_2)
```

> ```
>   Names Value_2
> 1     A      No
> 2     B      No
> 3     C      No
> 4     D     Yes
> ```